# Change value with onclick and javascript function

Tags: javascript, imagebutton, buttonclick, document.write

I am trying to change the value "qa". The js function works fine. However, I am not able to change the value "ID1" between span. When I click the image button plus, I want to change the value to 2 i.e. change value with one step, see also screenshot. The value 1 in the screenshot comes from document.write(qa).
I am new to this and I would appreaciate any help, thanks!

[Image: click on plus to change value with step 1 like from 1 to 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1xK4.png)

```js
   
var qa = 1;

function adq(x) {
  qa = qa + x;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="Group_1">
  <input type="image" id="Goup_m_1" src="some.png" name="submit_plus" onclick="adq(1)">
  <div id="Value">
    <span>Value</span>
  </div>
  <div id="ID1">
   <span>
     <script>
         document.write(qa);
     </script>
   </span>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the incremental value you have to get the div (`document.getElementById("ID1")`) and set `innerHTML` property in this way:

```js
function adq(x) {
  qa = qa + x;
  document.getElementById("ID1").innerHTML = qa;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="Group_1">
  <input type="image" id="Goup_m_1" src="some.png" name="submit_plus" onclick="adq(1)">
  <div id="Value">
    <span>Value</span>
  </div>
  <div id="ID1">
   <span>
     <script>
         var qa = 1;
         document.write(qa);
     </script>
   </span>
   </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the order of events:

1. Declare variable and assign it the value 1
2. Write the value (1) of that variable to the document
3. Click button and change value of the variable to 2

Step 2 happens before step 3!

The change to the value doesn't travel back in time so that when you read it to pass it to `document.write` it was 2.

If you want to change the text node in the document, then you need to *explicitly change that text node*.

MDN has a [guide to manipulating documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. I have created two js functions. One to calculate new value and one to show the incremental value. After onclick it calls both functions and displays the new value in span id=qa, which starts at value 1.

Thank you all for your help!

```js
var qa = 1;

        function adq() {
            qa = qa + 1;
        }

        function display() {
            document.getElementById("qa").innerHTML = qa;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<div id="Group_1">
  <input type="image" id="Gruppe_maskieren_1" src="Gruppe_maskieren_1.png" name="submit_adults_plus" onclick="adq();display();">
  <div id="Value">
    <span>Value</span>
  </div>
  <div id="ID1">
  <span id="qa">1</span> 
   </div>
</html>
```